# Does laying vinyl click flooring under appliances void the warranty?

Tags: flooring, kitchens

I have just had  a new kitchen installed and after all I decided to put a new floor which happens to be vinyl click panels. I was told that to make the floor to  look professional the installer would have to remove all appliances and re-installed them after laying the floor. I am wondering if  anyone has tried or knows if it possible to install vinyl panels around appliances similarly to laminate? I am just suspecting that re-installing the kitchen appliances would breach the terms of guarantee (five years from Wren).

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about the warranty or looking for opinions on appearance? If the warranty is only five years I wouldn't consider it worth having ugly edges showing around my appliances. Do it right and be happy.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding anything about that product. Maybe you could revise to post the language of the warranty related to appliances. You might just give them a call, though. Flooring isn't flooring if it can't be under things.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Although we can guess, really the answer is "it depends on the warranty terms." Have you read them?

Comment: This sounds like a better question for [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com)